# storing binary file(.jpg or .pdf) in google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I haven't seen any datatype to load unstructured data like image files or pdf files. Can anyone please explain, how to store the binary file(.jpg or .pdf) in google bigquery?

Comment: There is BYTES type for binary data.

Comment: Given that BigQuery is more expensive than pure storage like GCS, if you are not going to operate on the data, probably you want to place the files on GCS and only keep a path in BigQuery.